# HortonWorks HDP 2.6.5 or 2.5.0 : "My User Web Root" displayed instead of AMBARI

Tags: hadoop, virtualhost, hdp

I'm trying to follow the Udemy course on Hadoop, so I've no knowledge of Hadoop yet ;)

I've

- downloaded HDP_2.6.5_virtualbox_180626.ova (and I've also tested with 2.5.0 version) on my macbook (10.14.5)
- double click it to open the latest version of virtualbox (6.0.10),
- import
- set RAM to 10GB (over 32GB)
- run it
- I can see it unpacking and then the two URL (one for the welcome screen of hadoop, and one for the web ssh).

Opening the 1st URL, the Hortonworks welcome page, If I click the link to AMBARI I get a page with "My User Web Root" (so likely the default apache or nginx page).

It's as if it didn't map the hostname (127.0.0.1) to the correct virtual directory.
I've searched the logs and didn't find anything relevant to that issue.(there was some errors, but I can't tell if it's "normal errors" or not)

The advanced links works however, and the ssh webpage is working.
Ambari, Atlas, and Workflow Manager doesn't work (with a 502 bad gateway for atlas, "My User Web Root" for the two others).

**Any idea on how to fix that ?**

As 2.5.0 as the same behaviour, I was thinking it might be an issue of VirtualBox ? (since obviously it's working for a lot of people taking this course).